# Randomized image gallery without repeats

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a gallery with about 20 images that are randomly selected from the folder images/random. This is the code I've come up with so far, the problem is that it shows the same image all over the gallery. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
var array = ['1.jpg', ..., 100.jpg ]
var path = "images/random"

var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (array.length)),
image = array[index];

$(".random").attr("src", path + image);
```

HTML

```
<img class="random" src="" alt="">
```

Comment: Shuffle the array then grab an element. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array

Comment: Thank you! But once iv'e shuffled the array how do I cycle through  it assigning different src attributes for all my images?

Comment: Once it's shuffled you just need to loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you just generate a random image and see if it's been used, you'll eventually get to a point where you're rejecting almost every image you generate, which is a massive waste. Instead, randomize your array of images and just go through it in order.